# Losing firstResponder in ModalView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, modalviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I have next behavior:

1. UIView (A) has subView (B)
2. SubView B has buttons with actions
3. One of SubView's B actions opens ModalView (M) with textField (T) on it.
4. Clicking on textField (T) on ModalView (M) opens UIKeyboard, but UitextField (T) on ModalView (M) is no more firstResponder for this UiKeyboard and keyboard does not receive any user inputs.

Only UIKeyBoardWillShowNotification is calling.
Also, UIKeyBoardDidShowNotification is not calling in this ModalView...

How can i fix it? I know that somehow i have to move back responder to this UitextField (T) but how?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like very strange behaviour. What have you tried? Can't explain why it would be doing this, but could a solution be as simple as

```
[T becomeFirstResponder]
```

??

Comment: Yep, tryed it here:
<pre><code>
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) n 
{
    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
    
    for (UIView *v in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([v isFirstResponder]) {
            NSLog(@"Yes, textView is firstResponder. %@", v);
        }
    }
}
<pre><code>

Comment: Yes, tryed it in `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`:
`-(void) sss:(NSNotification *) n 
{
    //[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
    
    for (UIView *v in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([v isFirstResponder]) {
            NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! %@", v);
        }
    }
    
    NSLog(@"keyboard will show");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
[M resignFirstResponder]
[M setTarget:nil]
[T becomeFirstResponder]
```

Comment: Problem solved. 
I had to add ` [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` in parent UiViewController because it also has UITextField and it was catching UIKeyboardDidSHownNotification in ModalView.